# Unable To Find Table Functions In Information_Schema Schema

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

While reading INFORMATION_SCHEMA details on Snowflake documentation site URL Given below  ;  we can see 2  objects one is views and other is Table Functions.
Views provide that database specific objects (Tables, Functions , stages etc ) metadata where as Table Functions  can be used to return account level usages.
When i browsed though  Information Schema in each Databases i found only Views but not Table functions.

Have they moved these Table Functions

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema.html

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshot shows the "object browser" in the Snowflake WebGUI. In here you can only see views and tables, no table functions.

More info: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-worksheet.html

So... they are still there and you can execute them :-)

Edit: You can use `SHOW FUNCTIONS` to see all functions in your account.

Comment: Hi Marcel, thanks for your response, but i do not see here  the other option how to view table functions .

Comment: This is what I meant. You CANNOT see them there :-)

Comment: Then  do you know What is Other UI , to view list of UDFs, UDTFs under particular database/schema

Comment: You can use SHOW FUNCTIONS;